# Create Name Manager tables in excel with python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, ampl

Does xlsxwriter have the capability to add "name manager" tables to the excel file?

I am not referring to pivot tables but rather tables that are designated a defined range. I am in need of this feature to feed some files in to Monte Carlo simulation in AMPL which requires the named range. 
Here is an example:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Name-Manager-in-Excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4

Comment: seems possible 

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/the-vba-guide-to-named-ranges

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 10% clear on what you are looking for but you can add [tables](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html) and [defined names](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-define-name) with XlsxWriter.